# Majority voting of columns SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I need to do something like 'majority voting' of columns in SQL database. That means, that having columns: `c0`, `c1`, ..., `cn`, I would like to have in some other column for each row the most frequent value among mentioned columns (and `null` or random otherwise - it doesn't really matter). For example, if we have the following table:

```
+--+--+--+------+
|c0|c1|c2|result|
+--+--+--+------+
| 0| 1| 0|     0|
| 0| 1| 1|     1|
| 2| 2| 0|     2|
| 0| 3| 1|  null|
```

That is what I mean by majority voting of columns `c0`, `c1`, `c2`: in the first row we have 2 rows with value `0` and 1 with `1`, so `result = 0`. In the second we have one `0`'s vs two `1`'s, ergo `result = 1` and so on. We assume, that all the columns have the same type.

It would be great, if the query were concise (it can be build dynamically). Native SQL is preferred, but PL/SQL, psql will also do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tag only the DBMS you are using.

Comment: As said - postgresql or oracle. I'm ready to use, what is needed, although vendor agnostic solution would be appreciated.

Comment: No, when no value can be chosen, `null` or default can be inserted.

Comment: Only Oracle or Oracle and Postgres?

Comment: Any, I will take the one, that is capable of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done by creating a table out of the three columns and using an aggregate function on that:

The following works in Postgres:

```
select c0,c1,c2,
       (select c 
       from unnest(array[c0,c1,c2]) as t(c) 
       group by c 
       having count(*) > 1 
       order by count(*) desc 
       limit 1)
from the_table;
```

If you don't want to hard-code the column names, you can use Postgres' JSON function as well:

```
select t.*,
       (select t.v
        from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)) as t(c,v)
        group by t.v
        having count(*) > 1
        order by count(*) desc
        limit 1) as result
from the_table t;
```

Note that the above takes **all** columns into account. If you want to remove specific columns (e.g. an `id` column) you need to use `to_jsonb(t) - 'id'` to remove that key from the JSON value.

Neither of those solutions deals with ties (two different values appearing the same number of times).

Online example: https://rextester.com/PJR58760

---

The first solution can be "adapted" somewhat to Oracle, especially if you can build the SQL on the fly:

```
select t.*, 
       (select c
        from (
          -- this part would need to be done dynamically
          -- if you don't know the columns
          select t.c0 as c from dual union all 
          select t.c1 from dual union all 
          select t.c2 from dual
        ) x
        group by c
        having count(*) > 1
        order by count(*) desc
        fetch first 1 rows only) as result
from the_table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for Postgres.

```
SELECT t1.c0,
       t1.c1,
       t1.c2,
       (SELECT y.c
               FROM (SELECT x.c,
                            count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x.rn) ct
                            FROM (SELECT v.c,
                                         rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(v.c) DESC) rn
                                         FROM (VALUES (t1.c0),
                                                      (t1.c1),
                                                      (t1.c2)) v(c)
                                         GROUP BY v.c) x
                            WHERE x.rn = 1) y
               WHERE y.ct = 1) result
       FROM elbat t1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=5733e0714f540e86896a08a8b7c2a7b6)

In the subquery first all the values with maximum count are taken using `rank()`. The windowed version of `count()` is then used to filter if there is only one value with maximum count.

If you need to do this over more columns, just add them to the `SELECT` and the `VALUES`.

Comment: Maybe I didn't point it out right - type is known, values aren't, those could be, for example: 0, 2, 2.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres use [jsonb functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) You need primary key or unique column(s), `id` is unique in the example:

```
with my_table(id, c0, c1, c2) as (
values
    (1, 0, 1, 0),
    (2, 0, 1, 1),
    (3, 2, 2, 0),
    (4, 0, 3, 1)
)

select distinct on (id) id, value
from (
    select id, value, count(*)
    from my_table t
    cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)- 'id')
    group by id, value
    ) s
order by id, count desc

 id | value 
----+-------
  1 | 0
  2 | 1
  3 | 2
  4 | 1
(4 rows)
```

The query works well regardless of the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You can just compare the values.  For your example with two values neither of which is `NULL`:

```
select t.*
       (case when ((case when c0 = 0 then 1 else -1 end) +
                   (case when c1 = 0 then 1 else -1 end) +
                   (case when c2 = 0 then 1 else -1 end)
                  ) > 0
             then 0 else 1
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: I don't know the values - this couls be anything, only type is known. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Andronicus . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked.  I would suggest that you ask another question with more appropriate data.

Comment: Maybe, but it was stated originally, that only the type is known. I have added some additional example data :)